# c++: using a pointer to access a buffer vs using an incremental variable

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I am writing a delay based on a circular buffer. This is my implementation.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Fixed delay with circular buffer" << endl;
    int dtime = 5;
    int buffersize = 10;
    auto *in = new int[buffersize];
    auto *del = new int[dtime];
    auto *out = new int[buffersize];
    int p = 0;
    // zero-initialise the delay line
    for (int i = 0; i < dtime; i++) {
        del[i] = 0;
    }
    // fill the in buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) {
        in[i] = i;
    }

    // apply delay
    for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) {
        // read
        out[i] = del[p];
        // write
        del[p] = in[i];
        // update pointer
        p = (p != dtime-1? p+1 : 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) {
        cout << out[i] << ' ';
    }

    delete[] in;
    delete[] out;
    delete[] del;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result: `0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4`.

Reading from [this book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/audio-programming-book), the Author implements a pointer to the delay line for the writing/reading operations. That means, I have to make the `p` point to the head of the delay line, i.e. `int *p = del` and dereference the pointer when accessing the delay line, i.e. `out[i] = del[*p]` for the reading and `del[p] = in[i]` for the writing operation. Finally, I update the value as done before.

However,  I get this result: `8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`. Moreover, if I inspect the value inside the pointer, I get this progression `0 1 2 3 4 0 6 7 8 9`, which is quite strange.
I'm trying to understand why such a behaviour, since I expect the two version be the same.

I attach also the version with the pointer for completeness.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Fixed delay with circular buffer" << endl;
    int dtime = 5;
    int buffersize = 10;
    auto *in = new int[buffersize];
    auto *del = new int[dtime];
    auto *out = new int[buffersize];
    int *p = del;
    // zero-initialise the delay line
    for (int i = 0; i < dtime; i++) {
        del[i] = 0;
    }
    // fill the in buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) {
        in[i] = i;
    }

    // apply delay
    for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) {
        cout << *p << ' ';
        // read
        out[i] = del[*p];
        // write
        del[*p] = in[i];
        // update pointer
        *p = (*p != dtime-1? *p+1 : 0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < buffersize; i++) {
        cout << endl << out[i] << ' ';
    }

    delete[] in;
    delete[] out;
    delete[] del;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not handling the pointer correctly.  `*p` replaces the `del[p]` operation from the original code.

```
out[i] = *p;
*p = in[i];
```

The "update pointer" code then needs to update the pointer, not the value that it points to.

```
p = p != &del[dtime - 1] ? p + 1 : del;
```

or

```
if (++p == &del[dtime])
    p = del;
```

Comment: It does work, thanks very much. I have only two questions: 1) what is the preferable approach here? 2) The second version with the pointer comes from the book itself. I don't want to think that the code is not right, but why did they write it as such?

Comment: @MattiaPaterna The preferable approach is a matter of opinion.  The first way closely mirrors the original code, while I find the second way more readable.  I can't answer the second question.  However, errors in code published in books are not uncommon.  Perhaps you could try contacting the publisher.